# Size of a collection in LiteDb

Tags: litedb

Is it possible to get the size (disk space) of a collection?

I want to limit the size of the database and have a few collections, which grow in size over time. I want to delete older entries if the size of this collection is too large. Similar to a capped collection in mongoDb, but I'm not interested in the high-throughput operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In LiteDB it's possible to limit datafile file size, using `Limit Size` in connection string. This parameter limit growing file size (except journal area). 
When a document are deleted from any data page, this empty area will be used only this the same collection. If all documents are deleted from a page (4096 bytes) all this page are marked as empty and can be used for any other collection.

But, this resource are not available by collection, only for all database.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As work around I do something like this: 
1) look at one element in the collection and estimate the size with `GetBytesCount(bool recalc)`
2) I estimate the size of the collection with `Count(Query.All)`
3) I can estimate the number of old entries to delete

Follow up question: Is it possible to delete the first x entries in a collection? Right now i load alle entries with `col.Find(Query.All(), limit: numEntriesToDelete)` and then delete them individually